# Advice On Price Comparison Affiliate Programs

Tags: marketing, affiliate, comparison

I want a price comparison feature on my site similar to [Consumer Reports' "Price & Shop" section](http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/home-garden/lawn-garden/gas-grills/gas-grill-ratings/models/price-and-shop/buy-weber-q-200-99019684.htm). They use PriceGrabber.com, but as far as I can tell they have a special deal with CR, so I can't get a similar service for my site.

I've gathered that I need to use an affiliate network, but the whole thing seems so shady, I don't really know what sites are legit, and I don't know what sites offer the price comparison feature. [Datafeedfile.com](http://www.datafeedfile.com/) comes up a lot during my searches, but the ugly site makes me wary.

Does anyone have any experience with this? What affiliate networks do you recommend? Or should I be looking at something else altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rule for affiliate networks (advertising):
Try them, one by one.  If they don't work, stop using them.
They just tend to work for different types of products.

The ones that actually work best are the Google Price compare.
I think google calls these product fees (its free).